# Angular trigger event from service and wait for all subscribers to return a value

Tags: angular, events, openid-connect

I have a auth module , its using `oidc-client` as the base ...
I want to load some initial data about the user after its logged in ... but since these info are related to other modules and may change in the future , I don't want to hard code then in the auth service itself ...

So I was thinking of triggering on event when user is loaded ....

`public onUserLoading: BehaviorSubject<User> = new BehaviorSubject(this.user);`

```
    this._userManager    = new UserManager(this._getClientSettings());
    this.userLoadPromise = this._userManager.getUser();
    this.userLoadPromise.then(user => {
      this.user       = user;
      this.onUserLoading.next(user);
      //wait for the onUserLoading event to finish before setting this.userLoaded value
      this.userLoaded = true;
    });
```

But I need to wait for all the subscribers for `onUserLoading` to finish before proceeding to the next line code , but I don't know how !!!

Or is there a better way?

My last choice would be to create a list of listeners in auth module and everyone else  would add their promises to that list and auth module would simply just waits for all those promises to finish ...

Comment: what do you mean by " I need to wait for all the subscribers for onUserLoading to finish". These process that needs to finish are sync or async?
If they are sync, you can subscribe to the onUserLoading with take(1) and override the userLoaded flag when you get the value. But, I think it is not needed as when you emite, all subscribers will get value before next line because they will entry the event loop before the next line.

Comment: @BrunoJoão they are async http calls , need to load info about user from at-least 2 different api end points

Comment: In this case, you must know theses calls and wait for them. It is not possible for subscriber to say to the subject that they already processed the value without tell it what it needs to wait for. 
For that you use switchMap to call every http sequentially or a forkJoin to call all of them at the same time. `userManager.getUser().then(res => forkJoin([call1, call2, call3]).pipe(take(1)).subscribe(([res1, res2, res3]) => this.userLoaded = true; ));`. Tell me if it makes sense so I can writ it as an answer.

Comment: @BrunoJoão yeap that's kind of what I had in mind, tnx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the subscribers jobs are async, you must know theses jobs and wait for them to emit userLoaded.

It is not possible for the subscribers to say to the subject that they already processed the value without tell it what it needs to wait for.

For that you use switchMap to call every http sequentially or a forkJoin to call all of them at the same time.

```
userManager.getUser()
    .then(res => forkJoin([call1, call2,call3])
        .pipe(take(1))
        .subscribe(([res1, res2, res3]) => this.userLoaded = true)
    );
```

The `take(1)` is used to ensure the unsubscription of all subscribers. This operator completes when one value is "received". The argument is the number of values you want to "receive" before completing the stream. For example,  `take(3)` would receive 3 values and complete.

The `take(1)`can be removed if you are doing only http calls because the HttpCliente emits only one value and completes.

Comment: tnx, 1 question, what exactly `take(1)` do?